# Tangent cone to a set at a given point and first-order necessary optimality conditions

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research

Consider the problem of minimizing a continuously differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ with respect to $x$ in the set $$X = \{x: l_{j} \leq x_{j} \leq u_{j}, \, j=1,\cdots , n\}. $$

I need to do the following two things:

1. For $n =3$, I need to describe the tangent cone to $X$ at the point $\overline{x}=(l_{1},u_{2},a)^{T}$, where $l_{3}<a<u_{3}$.
2. Derive first-order necessary conditions of optimality for this problem.

**For #1**: My notes/text defines the **tangent cone** as the set $T_{X}(x)$ of all tangent directions for $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ at $x\in X$. And, a direction $d$ is called **tangent** to a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ at the point $x \in X$ and scalars $\tau_{k}>0$, $k = 1,2, \cdots $ such that $\tau_{k} \downarrow 0$ and $$d = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{x^{k}-x}{\tau_{k}}.$$

It also defines the tangent cone as the closure of the cone of feasible directions at $x \in X$: $$ T_{X}(x) = \overline{K_{X}(x)}= \overline{cone(X-x)}, $$ where $cone(X-x)$ is the cone generated by the convex set $X$. The set $X$ given in this problem seems to be convex by construction, but I do not know how to find the cone of feasible directions, and then determine its closure.

In fact, below is a graph of the feasible region in the specific case when $0 \leq x_{1} \leq 2$, $-1 \leq x_{2} \leq 4$, and $\frac{1}{2} \leq x_{3} \leq 1$:

[image]

**For #2**: I am not really sure what to do. I don't know if the system  $$ \text{minimize}_{x \in X} f(x) \\ \text{subject to} \\ x_{1} \geq l_{1} \\ x_{2} \geq l_{2} \\ x_{3} \geq l_{3} \\ x_{1} \leq u_{1} \\ x_{2} \leq u_{2} \\ x_{3} \leq u_{3} $$has metric regularity, so I don't know if there are any results that I can apply or even generally how to find the first-order necessary conditions. There are some results that I have seen for functions that are twice differentiable, but we are not guaranteed of that here - only that $f$ is continuously first differentiable.

Could somebody please help me? I am extremely lost, and not really understanding what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Have you drawn $X$? That should give you a pretty good idea for #1. As for #2, which necessary conditions do you know?

Comment: @user251257 I can't really visualize $X$. I know it's supposed to be in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, and from the way the point $\overline{x}$ is written, I assume that $x_{j}$ is the "$z$"-coordinate. So, I guess, It would look like a triangular prism? Am I right? For #2, I don't know what is applicable to this case, because I don't know if $X$ is convex or not.

Comment: ignore $\bar x$ first. $X$ doesn't depend on $\bar x$. Try to draw $X$ for $n=3$ and $l_1=\dotsb=l_3=0$ and $u_1=\dotsb=u_3=1$.

Comment: @user251257 isn't that a vertical plane? If every point is $(0,1,something)$ and that something is allowed to vary?

Comment: by definition $X = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \mid l_1 \le x_1 \le u_1 \land l_2 \le x_2 \le u_2 \land l_3 \le x_3 \le u_3 \}$. So $x_1$ and $x_2$ aren't fixed.

Comment: @user251257 Oh, I thought $l_{1}$ and $u_{1}$ WERE $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. I'm very confused...

Comment: look at the definition of $X$. $l_j$ is the **l**ower bound for $x_j$ and $u_j$ is the **u**pper bound.

Comment: @user251257 Oh, of course. So it's not a plane then. I have absolutely no idea how to draw that then.

Comment: well in my example $X=[0,1]^3$ is the unit cube. In general $X$ is a hyper-rectangle.

Comment: @user251257 well. That's certainly convex, then, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is convex.

Comment: @user251257 so its tangent cone is the closure of the cone generated by its extreme directions.

Comment: @user251257 there is a 100 point bounty on this question now.

Comment: Perhaps I can lead you to the solution. Consider unit square $X = [0,1]^2$ in 2D, which is easier to visualize than 3D perhaps. Can you determine the tangent cone to $X$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I can tell you what the normal cone is - it's the unit square  $Y = [-1,0]^2 $. But not the tangent cone. Perhaps my difficulty is understanding what the definition of the tangent cone is actually saying?

Comment: Ok, well, let's start with the normal cone then. What is its definition, and how are you computing it?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong well for that particular example that you just did, I was able to do it visually.  But it turns out that the $Y$ I gave is not the normal cone, it's the dual cone to $X$. The definition I have of the normal cone is: "Consider a convex closed set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a point $x \in X$. The set $N_{X}(x) = [cone(X-x)]^{\circ}$ is called the normal cone to $X$ at x", which looks to me like it's the polar of the Tangent Cone, based on the definition for the tangent cone that I gave in my original question. My book goes on to say that "$v \in N_{X}(x)$ iff...

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong (continued) ... iff $\langle v, y-x \rangle \leq 0$ for all $y \in X$." I doubt you're going to be able to lead me to an answer this way though. I really do not understand the definition of the tangent cone and I don't know how it's going to help me come up with any first-order necessary conditions.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong posting an answer where you explain all of this, including what the definition of the tangent cone is actually saying and how generally to go about finding it (including in this case) would probably be the most instructive.

Comment: I'd be happy to explain #1 in detail. I have no idea what #2 is talking about; it would help if you could point me to a reference on what exactly *"first-order necessary conditions of optimality"* are.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that's more than I have so far, and I might be able to figure out the second part if I knew what the tangent cone is, because apparently, they're related.

Comment: I am curious, what text are you using?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: A typical characterisation of a first order necessary condition would be that at an optimal point $x$ we have $\langle \nabla f(x),  h \rangle \ge 0 $ for all $x \in T_X(x)$. Since the constraints defining $X$ are affine, the tangent cone (or rather its polar) has a nice characterisation and the ballyhooed 'constraint qualification' is satisfied. I am guessing the goal here is to obtain something like $-\nabla f(x) \in T_X(x)^\circ$.

Comment: Your definition of the tangent cone doesn't describe what $x_k$ is.

Comment: @copper.hat we're using this text: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0691119155/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1509916841&sr=8-2&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=nonlinear+optimization&dpPl=1&dpID=513JvbdIpFL&ref=plSrch

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the clarification.  What exactly does the $\circ$ in $T_X(x)^\circ$ mean in this context?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The polar.

Comment: @copper.hat perfect, thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat is that the first-order conditions we want here? From the way the problem is phrased, I'm assuming the constraints are affine. There is a Theorem in my text stating "Assume $\hat{x}$ is local minimum of constrained minimization problem (in the preceding part, it seems to imply that $\hat{x}$ is a boundary point, which makes sense since $X$ is convex) and $f(\cdot)$ is differentiable at $\hat{x}$. Let $T_{x}(\hat{x})$ be the tangent cone to $X$ at $\hat{x}$. Then $-\nabla f(\hat{x})\in [T_{X}(\hat{x})]^{\circ}$." So it seems like you got it exactly right for this case...

Comment: @copper.hat correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking so I can't give a precise answer. It is not necessarily the case that the minimum occurs at a boundary point, if not the tangent space will be the whole space. I am guessing the question is asking for the gradient formulation of the 1st order conditions and then asking you to write these in the context of the tangent cone in question. The answer that I imagine they are trying to lead you to is to note that the 1st order conditions are equivalent to the projected gradient (onto the box) being zero, which is a nice geometric result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do some work to follow this answer.

The idea behind the tangent cone is to have a model of the constraint space $X$ that shows the directions we can move from a particular point $x$ **and** remain in the constraint space.

Be aware that there are various definitions of tangent cones, not all are the same. The following is specific to the particular definition
used in the question.

Since $X$ is convex, the tangent cone is convex. From the definition it follows that the tangent cone is closed.

It is not hard to show (assuming that $f$ is $C^1$ at $x$) that if $\langle \nabla f(x), d \rangle < 0$ for some $d \in T_X(x)$, then there is some (nearby) $y \in X$ such that
$f(y) < f(x)$. Hence if $x$ is a local minimiser, we must have
$\langle \nabla f(x), d \rangle \ge 0$ for all $d \in T_X(x)$ or, in
other words, $-\nabla f (x) \in T_X(x)^\circ$.

**Note**: Most first order conditions boil down to something of this form, but
usually more work is needed to make this condition 'usable'.

A small amount of work is needed to compute $T_X(x)$ and its polar.

This can be done directly, or by using Lemma 3.13 of Ruszczynski's "Nonlinear Optimization" which states that when $X$ is convex $T_X(x) = \overline{K_X(x)}$, the closure of the cone of feasible directions.
(Since $X$ is a box with straight edges, we see that, in fact, $T_X(x) = K_X(x)$.)

Working with an interval first illustrates the idea: Suppose $n=1$ and
$X=[l,u]$. If $x=l$ then clearly we can only change in a positive direction and so $T_X(l) = [0,\infty)$, and similarly, if $x=u$ we
can only change in a negative direction, so $T_X(u) = (-\infty,0]$. If $x \in (l,u)$ then we can move either way so $T_X(x) = (-\infty,\infty)$.

Note that $T_X(l)^\circ = (-\infty,0]$, $T_X(x)^\circ = \{0\}$ and
$T_X(u)^\circ = [0,\infty)$ (with $x \in (l,u)$). In particular, if $x$ is a local minimiser of $f$ for this one dimensional problem, then if $x=l$ we must have $f'(l) \ge 0$, if $x \in (l,u)$ we must
have $f'(x) = 0$ and if $x=u$ we must have $f'(u) \le 0$.

For the $X$ given in the question, note that since the edges of the box are parallel to the axes, a direction $d$ at a point $x\in X$ is
a feasible direction **iff** each individual component $d_k$ is a
feasible direction for the corresponding constraint $l_k \le x_k \le u_k$.

Let $L(x) = \{ k | x = l_k \}, U(x) = \{ k | x = u_k \}$. Note that $L(x),U(x)$ are always disjoint and may be empty.

In particular, $d$ is a feasible direction **iff** for all $k$ we have
$d _k \in \begin{cases} [0,\infty),& k \in L(x) \\
(-\infty,0],& k \in U(x) \\
(-\infty,\infty),& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. Lemma 3.13 tells
us that this is, in fact, $T_X(x)$.

We can compute $T_X(x)^\circ$ from this.
Note that $\langle y , t \rangle \le 0$ for all $t \in T_X(x)$ **iff**
$y _k \in \begin{cases} (-\infty,0],& k \in L(x) \\
[0,\infty),& k \in U(x) \\
\{0\},& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

From this, we see that if $x$ is a local minimiser, then we must have
${\partial f(x) \over \partial x_k } \in \begin{cases} [0,\infty),& k \in L(x) \\
(-\infty,0],& k \in U(x) \\
\{0\},& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

As a sanity check, note that if the upper and lower bound constraints 
are inactive, this boils down to $\nabla f(x) = 0$ which is the
unconstrained first order condition.

**Two final notes**:

(i) There are different definitions of the tangent cone, some
more liberal, some more stringent. In practice, if $X$ is convex, they typically end up being the same thing.

(ii) In many cases, the gradient inclusion first order condition 
provides less information that might appear at first glance. For example, the problem $\min \{ f (x) | x^2 = 0 \}$ ends up with
$T_X(0) = \{0\}$ and hence $T_X(0)^\circ = \mathbb{R}$, hence it
does not place any constraints on $f$ at all. Sometimes people add 'constraint qualifications' that allow the polar cone to be written in a nicer fashion.

Comment: is the polar that Omnomnomnom calculated correct? And if so, wouldn't its polar just be $\{(x,y,z): x\leq 0, y \geq 0\}$?

Comment: It is. It would be, and is. If you work through the formula above for $n=3$ you will end up with the same result??? You do need to some some work here!

Answer (score 1):

For #1: the region $X - \bar x$ will simply be
$$
X - \bar x = \{(x,y,z) : 0 \leq x \leq (u_1 - l_1),(l_2 - u_2) \leq y \leq 0,(l_3 - a) \leq z \leq (u_3 - a) \}
$$
To see why, it may help to note that $X - \bar x$ is simply $\{y - \bar x : y \in X\}$.  To that end, we find that
$$
X - (a_1,a_2,a_3) = 
\left\{(x,y,z) : \begin{array}{c}(l_1 - a_1) \leq x \leq (u_1 - a_1)\\(l_1 - a_2) \leq y \leq (u_2 - a_2)\\(l_3 - a_3) \leq z \leq (u_3 - a_3)\end{array} \right\}
$$

The closed convex cone generated by this region is the smallest set containing $X - \bar x$ which is closed under multiplication by positive scalars and addition. Because $X - \bar x$ is already convex, finding the closed convex cone simply amounts to extending all rays indefinitely, then taking the closure.

In this case, 
$$
T_X(\bar x) = \{(x,y,z) : x \geq 0, y \leq 0\}
$$

Comment: (hopefully, that was enough noms), could you explain a little more how you determined that $X-\overline{x}$ was the set you provided? Thank you.

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys I added a bit, see if that clears things up.

Comment: don't you mean $X-\overline{x}=\{(x,y,z):0\leq x \leq (u_{1}-l_{1}), (l_{2}-u_{2})\leq y \leq 0, (l_{3}-a)\leq z \leq (u_{3}-a)\}$?

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys of course! Took me a while to notice that I wrote $x$ all 3 times, sorry.